# VB.net How do I remove items from a list that are already in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

So I am making Deal or No Deal and i'm currently trying to randomise what case holds what amount of money. At the moment my code creates the list of values and then randomises a selection which then inputs into the array. It then outputs to the console the 26 values. Now when a value from the list is selected and inputed into the array i want that value to be removed from the list. So then when the loop repeats and chooses another item from the list, and it can no longer select the one that was chosen in the previous loop.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim values = New List(Of Integer)({0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 80, 100, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 80000, 100000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 850000, 1000000, 10000000})
    Dim sselect = New Random()
    Dim cases(25) As Integer

    For i = 0 To cases.Length - 1

        cases(i) = sselect.Next(0, values.Count)
        Console.WriteLine(values(cases(i)))
    Next

End Sub
```

I tried to use `RemoveAll` and then `AddressOf` to remove the duplicate values, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
        values.RemoveAll(AddressOf cases)
```

Comment: If you read the fine manual on `System.Random`, there is a section that discusses a potential way to use `Random` to shuffle.  See the section, "Retrieve a unique element from an array or collection."

Comment: The first element of your list, 0.5, is not an Integer.

Comment: AddressOf is looking for a method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?view=netframework-4.7.2) while choosing the amounts which:

> Removes the element at the specified index of the List.

Like this:

```
For i = 0 To cases.Length - 1
    cases(i) = sselect.Next(0, values.Count)
    Console.WriteLine(values(cases(i)))
    values.RemoveAt(cases(i))
Next
```

Using this way will remove the used value from the list `values` right on the spot, which in turn won't allow duplicate values to be chosen.

I suggest that you keep a copy of the original list before iterating through that. A fast and simple way is to create the list twice at the start.

```
Dim values = New List(Of Integer)({0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 80, 100, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 80000, 100000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 850000, 1000000, 10000000})
Dim original = New List(Of Integer)({0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 80, 100, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 80000, 100000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 850000, 1000000, 10000000})
```

This way after removing all of them from the `values` list. You'll still have them in `original` list. Assuming you'll reuse them later on.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way:

```
Dim rng As New Random
Dim cases = {0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 80, 100, 500, 750, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 80000, 100000, 150000, 250000, 500000, 850000, 1000000, 10000000}.OrderBy(Function(dbl) rng.NextDouble()).ToList()
```

Done!  By the way, how are you going to store 0.5 in a `List(Of Integer)`?

EDIT:

In my original code, the end result would be an `IEnumerable(Of Double)`.  I should have added a called to `ToList` to get a `List(Of Double)`, which I have now added.

The code uses an implicitly-typed array and, because there is a `Double` value in there, the array is inferred to be type `Double`.  All the `Integer` values are implicitly converted to `Doubles`.  If you want a `List(Of Decimal)` instead of a `List(Of Double)`then simply change `0.5`, which is a `Double` literal, to `0.5D`, which is a `Decimal` literal.

Comment: Yes I changed it to Decimal from Integer, would this method still work with decimal?